# Empty lines in code samples inside lists are shown duplicated

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

If I put a code block in a list, a single newline in the source is displayed as two newlines in the rendered page:

1. Sample:

   ```
   code here, single empty line following:

   more code here
   ```
2. ...

(The eight space indent is markdown for "inside the list *and* a code block").
The same happens for unordered lists, but inside quotations everything works fine. One empty line in the source should correspond to one empty line in the output.

Comment: How interesting… Here is the source, for those interested http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/cfda7d33-f2f3-40dd-a104-a2c5916ea6e6/view-source

Comment: Well, great, so the error is in Markdown _everywhere_.  Is Markdown divine?  Is something that seems wrong to everyone's eyes an error of the eyes now?  Does this really warrant a "status-bydesign"?

Answer (score 1):

See answer here

[Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/bug-in-markdown-formatter/19799#19799)

Comment: I sure believe that it's broken and has always been broken.  I've read your blog entry on poor parenting of open-source software.  But could you kindly edit to explain that you think it's better to be consistent with markdown's no bugs than to format code inside lists well?  (I sort of think that's your position, but I'm not certain, and I'd sure like to know why.)

Answer (score 0):

Seen, but it does make it hard to write nice answers for the archives:

[lua - metadata for documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100062/lua-metadata-for-documentation/3102703#3102703)