# Revision bug, bad formating

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff)

If you check out the revision, you'll see it is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2619425/revisions starting at "Why would I ever not be allowed " should be normal text

It doesnt affect markdown page or view so it isnt bad.