# Revision history code formatting bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

Take a look at revision 2 in [this edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6316996/revisions). The revision appears to have nested code groups and is clearly malformatted:

[image: Malformed code in revision history]

However, clicking through to view [the actual revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6316996/2) as it *really* appeared, one can see that it was formatted just fine:

[image: Well-formed code in actual revision]

Comment: Possible dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff, but I'm not really sure. The question had no image screenshot attached so it's hard to tell whether he was originally talking about the same thing, or whether the post he links to has acquired this behaviour _since then_.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lO46S.png; see http://superuser.com/posts/310779/revisions and http://superuser.com/questions/310779/vmware-player-and-windows-7-network-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.

Comment: Take a look at [revision 3 here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7374421/revisions). Even the tags _under_ the revision content are now susceptible to formatting issues relating to code blocks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. That certainly doesn't look right.

Comment: Fixed in the next build.

Comment: I don't know whether you've pushed that build already, but it appears to be fixed. :)

Comment: No, I haven't, and it's not fixed: Click "full" to show the full revision diff (not just the condensed version), and you'll still see the issue. The "condense to only the changed parts" was deployed after you noticed this.

Comment: Oh, yes. That's new.

Comment: That's got it. And I **love** the diff mode selection buttons. Love, love, love, love them. <3