# Revision diff viewer doing something funky with tag: syntax

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface, revisions-list

[This answer edit that I just made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99893/revisions) looks a little bit funky in the revision history:

[image: Nice tag there bro]

The edit just went from

> there is also a `[tag:lucene-compass]` tag for ...

to

> there is a separate tag for ...

So I'm not sure what would be causing it, since it seems like a pretty straightforward change.

For reference, I'm seeing this in both FF5 and Chrome latest on Windows XP (yes, I know...)

Comment: This is yet another case of the more general problems we have with the revision diffs. It does the exact same thing with links, code blocks, bold/italics, etc.

Comment: Other questions documenting this include: [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/), [Revisions overly italicizes text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91263/), [Revision history code formatting bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94753/), [Possible bug in previous versions' user interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92039/), [Wrong formatting after edit.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71809/), [Revision bug, bad formating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46334/)

Comment: @Cody those are all revision history formatting bugs but not the same as this as this has to do with `[tag:]` syntax.  Potentially related, though.

Comment: Definitely related. It's doing exactly the same thing: applying the special formatting to the entire rest of the post. There's nothing special about the fact that it's a tag. This has been documented for all kinds of other formatting types. Not sure what the hold-up has been on fixing it, though. I guess it's because we use a third-party tool for diffs, rather than something coded up in-house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm. We're currently testing it here on Meta (it will go out to the other sites once we're certain there are no problems), and you can see that the diff now looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

The wonky revision history is echoed in the html:

```
</a></div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lucene-compass" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'lucene-compass'" rel="tag">
<table width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 800px;" align="left">

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
                    </a></div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lucene-compass" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'lucene-compass'" rel="tag">
                </a></td>
```

So I don't think this is a browser specific bug.  I believe this is a bug with the diff engine.