# Post revision incorrectly renders subsequent codeblocks as nested

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff)

[Revision 2 here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/16350/revisions) ends up being visualised as a codeblock in another codeblock, when no such thing is present in the post.

[image: revision of post #16350 on unix.SE]

This is obviously a bug. I haven't tried to narrow it down.