# Incorrect formatting in viewing a revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff)

See [the list of revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7176061/revisions) for [Problem with a Moving & Rotating Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176061/problem-with-a-moving-rotating-map)

[The fifth revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7176061/5) looks like it has not correctly formatted the edits: It created several nested code blocks, when the actual post has several, non-nested ones. Compare the revision with [its source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2354c0c9-0ff0-4429-baa3-7d709130d156/view-source).

Comment: The [link to revision 5](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7176061/5) you provided exhibits no bugs. One should directly look at the [list of revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7176061/revisions) and view #5 there. The source of the trouble is that the changes are shown. This often causes problems, and it not only for code blocks.