# HTML - How to post HTML in StackOverflow

Tags: support, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HowTo Post HTML Text On StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48092/howto-post-html-text-on-stackoverflow)

I need to post some HTML code here for illustrating my questions. However, whenever I post the HTML, it is always interpreted by the page rather than display it directly.

I have tried the following methods, none of them work for me.

< XMP >

< /XMP >

< PRE >
< /PRE >

< CODE >
< /CODE >

Comment: You simply need to indent your code with 4 spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML - How to post HTML in StackOverflow http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9568/codeso.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9568/codeso.png)

Comment: This button is no longer available

Answer (score 4):

Click the button which has:

```
101
010
```

on it!

Post any code you like.

```
<html>
<body>
<div></div><p>a p tag</p><table><tr><td>some td</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This button is no longer available

Comment: @Madbreaks I believe you are correct.

Comment: So how do we do it now?