# Markdown parsing bug: Code block inside numbered list

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists)

**Consider the following Markdown input:**

```
1. Blah

        void Main()
        {
            Line 1

            Line 2
```

**Actual behaviour:** This is currently rendered into the following HTML. I have removed the `<span>` and `<code>` tags that pertain to the syntax highlighting, the outer `<ol>` tag, and I have indented it to make the bug more obvious. Notice that there is a `<pre>` nested inside another `<pre>`:

```
<li>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <pre class="prettyprint">
        void Main()<br>
        {<br>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; Line 1<br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <pre class="prettyprint">
            Line 2<br>
        </pre>
        <br><br>
    </pre>
</li>
```

**Expected behaviour** is something more like this:

```
<li>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <pre class="prettyprint">
        void Main()<br>
        {<br>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; Line 1<br>
        <br>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; Line 2
    </pre>
</li>
```