# Problem with markdown rendering?

Tags: support, markdown

#### What I want:

1. Foo
2. Bar

   That, or baz!
3. Spam
4. Egg

---

#### What I tried:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar

  That, or baz!

3. Spam
4. Egg
```

---

#### What I get:

1. Foo
2. Bar

   That, or baz!
3. Spam
4. Egg

---

For some reason, adding a paragraph to a list item also adds a paragraph to the following list item. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists/74115#74115) includes some info about when list items are wrapped in paragraph tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct markdown:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar

  That, or baz!
3. Spam
4. Egg
```