# Part of my post was replaced with random gibberish

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, posting

[An answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5419/1) that I posted on Meta.Programmers was rather broken, with a block quote replaced by apparently random letters and numbers. Aarthi fixed it with a non-breaking space, but I don't understand what went wrong.

When I opened the post for editing, the displayed text was what I intended to go there. It only happens when the post is viewed in the reading mode. The preview also displayed the text correctly.

Comment: Go home Thomas, you're drunk ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa I am home and I'm not drunk. That was the other day.

Comment: That looks like a hash-out string that didn't get replaced properly when Markdown finished.

Comment: @animuson I wonder if it has to do with the combination of ? - > to end a question and start the new bullet quote block? Could be a Markdown bug, but I don't know why the preview would be fine and the post not be.

Comment: My first guess is that it's strongly related to [Blockquotes in a list break blockquotes after the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153326), but I'll check more when I get back from dinner.

Comment: You're not drunk... The hat you're wearing suggests otherwise.

Comment: Related? [Quoting codes in a list leaves a `</li>`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5942/5764)

Answer (score 8):

The main issue is that Markdown parser can sometimes be a bit fragile when it comes to lists and block quotes, because the boundaries aren't as well-terminated as, say, code blocks.

Barring a fix, the user-side resolution of the problem is to make the parser's job as easy as possible, which in your case would have involved the Markdown:

```
 - > does something exist like this for full-text indexing/searching?

 - > Has anyone ever had a similar gripe before... or am I nuts and should just keep using SQL for these situations?
```

which renders as

- > does something exist like this for full-text indexing/searching?
- > Has anyone ever had a similar gripe before... or am I nuts and should just keep using SQL for these situations?

Note that the `>` is on the same line as the `-`, and that the newline between the two list items is necessary for everything to turn out right.

So, what goes wrong in your case? As I [alluded to in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161275/part-of-my-post-was-replaced-with-random-gibberish#comment468324_161275), you're actually being bitten by a blockquote-in-list bug which occurs with the *second* blockquote, which in turn is responsible for the bug you're actually seeing here.

While it'll take a bit more troubleshooting to see if there's a fix [for the underyling issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153326/blockquotes-in-a-list-break-blockquotes-after-the-list), the trouble starts when the HTML block replacement for the second block quote inadvertently eats the closing `</li></ul>` from the list, leaving the parser with this (where `?` is standing in for a non-printable character):

```
...\n\n<ul>\n<li>?H2035416125H</li>\n<li>\n\n\n?H977440878H\n\n...
```

Since there's no longer a closing tag for the list, the second call to `HashHTMLBlocks` that handles Markdown-generated blocks doesn't swap out the list as intended. This causes the input to `FormParagraphs` to be malformed, since even though it recursively subsitutes back in hashed blocks, it expects the top level block to be proceeded by two newlines.

Had the entire `<ul>` block been swapped out, this would have been fine, but because the other issue caused it not to be, the first hash marker `?H2035416125H` fails the regex match and no replacement is performed.

Luckily, addressing the linked issue should cause this problem to simply go away. I've [suggested some quick-fixes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153326/blockquotes-in-a-list-break-blockquotes-after-the-list/161414#161414) for that problem, so we'll see what balpha thinks.

Answer (score 5):

### Example

#### Source

```
 - 

> This text is going to be replaced.
 - 
> This text is going to remain.
```

#### HTML Output

```
<p><ul>
<li>H708767747H</li>
<li></p>

<blockquote>
  <p>This text is going to remain.</li>
  </ul></p>
</blockquote>
```

#### Rendered Output

- > This text is going to be replaced.
- > This text is going to remain.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by [Unexpected text at the bottom of posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277023/unexpected-text-at-the-bottom-of-posts/277125#277125). If you look at the [revision view of Jeremy Banks' test answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/161277/1) or at the previously broken first revision [of your own answer on meta.programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5419/1) (revision views are always live, so you see what the Markdown conversion does *today*), you'll see that it looks fine.

To be clear, the broken nesting of the HTML is still there – it looks like this now:

```
<ul>
<li><blockquote>
  <p>This text is going to be replaced.</p>
</blockquote></li>
<li>

<blockquote>
  <p>This text is going to remain.</li>
  </ul></p>
</blockquote>
```

– but the browser graciously works around that. That's the bigger general problem of blockquotes in lists* (and reported in various places), but at least there's no "H708767747H" anymore.

<sub>*That is [also fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259111/115866).</sub>