# Prettify claims the whole post body

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting, internet-explorer-8

The first edition of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15692844/11683

Seems like the question text is all prettified despite it's not formatted as all code.
Does not happen in the preview.

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: I see only *one* edition of that question, and it is not prettified as a whole. Do you have a screenshot? Was it editing in the grace period? Are you certain you are not looking at a stale version, clicking `edit` loads the *current* version, which could have been fixed already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see only one edition, too. I said "first edition" in case a second edition appears while I type. Attached a screenshot.

Comment: What browser, what platform? That is not what I see. The `For Each` line is not broken into two lines, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters IE8 on Windows7. If I forcefully reload the post, the correct layout momentarily appears and then prettify breaks the `for` and colors it all. As I said, this does not happen if I try to edit the post -- the preview looks as it should, which is the only reason I'm posting it as a bug despite it's IE8.

Comment: That still could be a bug in IE8. It's a fragile beast, IE8. Sometimes things break, sometimes they do not.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not immediately sure what causes things to break (something to do with the manual `<pre>` blocks*), but you should turn off Compatibility Mode and things should be fine:

[image: compatibility mode button]

I've also edited the post to use Markdown code blocks, which seems to resolve the issue even in Compatibility Mode.

*They had unbalanced `<code>` tags inside and outside their `<pre>` tags, which throws IE 8 off. I'm on an iPad right now so I can't easily account for the difference in rendered versus preview, but its likely similar to the case on [Blockquotes in a list break blockquotes after the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153326/blockquotes-in-a-list-break-blockquotes-after-the-list) (which also involved unbalanced tags, but at the fault of the Markdown parser instead of the user)

Comment: IE wasn't in compatibility mode so I didn't have anything to turn off.

Comment: Ah, hmm. I tested in IE 9, so I guess the rendering bug that was triggered in compatibility mode must be present in IE 8's normal mode. I'll see if I can find a machine with IE 8 to dig further.

Answer (score -1):

Marking as declined -- we don't support visual glitches for this version of IE.