# Markdown escapes rendered HTML as code block

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

This inserts HTML for the link in the JavaScript preview and also when output on site:

[image]

---

Here as code, make normal input:

```
I want to setup PHP for command line usage on my Windows 8 64 bit. I did not manage to do this though.

What I did so far is:

1. download and run 
>     http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/ 
      Wednesday, July 10, 2013  9:57 PM
      php-5.3.27-win32-VC9-x86.msi (I did choose win32 as there was no win64)
2. Within this walkthrough  I did choose "default location", "no server" and some extentions for php. the installer told me everything went successfully.
3. I did restart my PC. went to command line and typed in: php

I received:

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to change anything in `php.ini`?
```

---

Rendering; See teletyped HTML link to http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/

---

I want to setup PHP for command line usage on my Windows 8 64 bit. I did not manage to do this though.

What I did so far is:

1. download and run

   > ```
   > http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/
   > ```
   >
   > Wednesday, July 10, 2013  9:57 PM
   >     php-5.3.27-win32-VC9-x86.msi (I did choose win32 as there was no win64)
2. Within this walkthrough  I did choose "default location", "no server" and some extentions for php. the installer told me everything went successfully.
3. I did restart my PC. went to command line and typed in: php

I received:

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to change anything in `php.ini`?

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem? The URL is linkified by-design.

Comment: As code template?

Comment: Is it supposed to be on Meta or I'm missing something?

Comment: ah, I can see that. @Marc-Andre The link is wrapped in HTML and the HTML is displayed as code. Definitely a bug.

Comment: You should trim the example to only the faulty link. This looks like you're asking the original question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the order of events is for this, but you're putting a code block inside a blockquote inside a list item, and to the Markdown parser it's all *inline* because you don't have an extra line-break between the list item text and the blockquote. Technically, this is invalid syntax. If there's a real bug here, it's that the blockquote shouldn't actually get rendered in this situation.

Comment: (Likely) Related issue: [Blockquotes in a list break blockquotes after the list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153326)

Comment: What were you trying to do, anyway? Get a code block inside of a blockquote inside of a list item?

Comment: So I now added a screenshot. @TimStone I entered text and then I saw that some HTML is generated where I assue no HTML belongs to so I smelled some flaw in the code so I reported it so it is reported. I'm not the developer of the underlying code to analyse it further, I just report it.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Yes exactly that. It normally works.

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing the Markdown parsers with your syntax.

1. If you want a

   > quote
2. within a list, you need whitespace on either side, and one space in from of the `>` quote marker. Nothing special about URLs:

   > http://meta.stackexchange.com

   http://meta.stackexchange.com
3. If you want some code inside that quote, then:

   > ```
   > void foo(int bar);
   > ```
   >
   > does the trick.

What you had there is not valid Markdown, you always need whitespace between different elements.

- Gets

  > a bit

  - tedious

    > after

    - a while

      > though.

---

```
You're confusing the Markdown parsers with your syntax.

1. If you want a

 > quote

2. within a list, you need whitespace on either side, and one space in from of the `>` quote marker. Nothing special about URLs:

 > http://meta.stackexchange.com

 http://meta.stackexchange.com

3. If you want some code inside that quote, then:

 >     void foo(int bar);

 > does the trick.

What you had there is not valid Markdown, you always need whitespace between different elements.

* Gets

 > a bit

 * tedious

     > after

     * a while

         > though.
```

Comment: You are using the concept of *invalid Markdown* which remains undefined. I'm pretty sure the way you coin that concept is inherently wrong. Also you must have misunderstood my report here, I'm in no way looking for guidance how to format a question, I can perfectly do that. This here on Meta is just a report of the flaw which signals an underlying bug. As it is HTML related I thought it's worth to report it not that some kind of weird injection scheme is hiding somewhere.

Comment: If there's no formal syntax for markdown, how can you say that the way I coin it is wrong? (I had initially understood your question as a plain bug report. Comments on minitech's answers made me think I might have mis-understood.)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists <= the closest you'll get for a syntax guide. Notice the vertical whitespace, @hakre

Comment: Which part of "not a syntax question" didn't you understand? ;) I might have misread your answer then wrong if it was more directed to @minitech s markdown syntax question / speculation. Sorry for that. However there is no such thing as valid / invalid markdown because markdown extends HTML. If there is "invalid" markdown it's just plain text. However that link in plain text is not a HTML link. I did read your answer like saying it actually is and then I'd say that would be inherently wrong. Maybe this clarifies this.

Comment: Oh, you weren’t referencing an actual section number? Got it :D

Answer (score 2):

It looked like you wanted this:

```
I want to setup PHP for command line usage on my Windows 8 64 bit. I did not manage to do this though.

What I did so far is:

1. download and run
> http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/  
> Wednesday, July 10, 2013  9:57 PM  
> php-5.3.27-win32-VC9-x86.msi (I did choose win32 as there was no win64)
2. Within this walkthrough  I did choose "default location", "no server" and some extentions for php. the installer told me everything went successfully.
3. I did restart my PC. went to command line and typed in: php

I received:

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to change anything in `php.ini`?
```

Interestingly enough, that doesn’t render the second blockquote!

---

I want to setup PHP for command line usage on my Windows 8 64 bit. I did not manage to do this though.

What I did so far is:

1. download and run

   > http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/
   >   Wednesday, July 10, 2013  9:57 PM
   >   php-5.3.27-win32-VC9-x86.msi (I did choose win32 as there was no win64)
2. Within this walkthrough  I did choose "default location", "no server" and some extentions for php. the installer told me everything went successfully.
3. I did restart my PC. went to command line and typed in: php

I received:

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to change anything in `php.ini`?

---

Er, this is sort of another bug, not an answer. But I think it does answer what the original formatting ought to be.

Comment: That's not correct markdown either, you need an empty line after `1. foo`, and a space before the `>`. `1. foo\n\n > bar\n\n2. bob`

Comment: @Mat: Sure, but why does it ruin an unrelated block while rendering “properly”?

Comment: That's in the Markdown Standard §42.3.2.1.1/3: "_[...] leads to undefined behavior [...]_". Or something. Once the parser's confused, it stays confused.

Comment: @Mat: So that’s the issue in the question, then, too? You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as expected from the next build on, as a side-effect of [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259111/115866).