# Markdown parsing bug; backticks and paragraph break not being applied

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

When I view revision 3 of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451773/1709587) in the edit preview, the final two paragraphs render correctly:

[image: Everything is fine]

However, when viewing the answer normally, the conversion from markdown to HTML is broken. The penultimate paragraph does not get wrapped in a `<p>` tag as it should, and the backticks within it are spat out literally and not converted to a code block:

[image: Everything is fucked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was yet another fallout from the broken handling of tight lists, which is [fixed in the next build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259111/115866).

Comment: I had to make a token edit to my post to cause the fix to take effect. Will you be recompiling all posts site-wide to implement the fix? Is this process underway?

Comment: @MarkAmery No, we don't do anything like that. We have something like 30 million questions and answers. Let's say 100ms to render a post (I don't know what the average time there is, but the ballpark should be correct), that's about 35 machine-days to re-render them all. Doing something like that for an issue that impacts a very small number of posts and that *visibily* impacts even fewer is not something we would consider.

Comment: @MarkAmery Also, for any change to Markdown we make there are posts out there that *rely* on the old behavior and that look broken after the change (I give on example for this particular case in the linked post). While that is not a good reason not to improve Markdown, it would still be nice not to break those old posts, and by deferring re-rendering to the next time a post is edited (which also means that a human looks at it), we achieve just that.