# Single line code formatting after list not working

Tags: bug, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)
>   [Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists)

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544034/1488917) the first line of code in the question is being displayed properly. The background of the other code sections are different from the background of the first code block.

---

[image]

Comment: I've seen this problem when you try to post code in a list or just after a list (as you're doing).

Comment: its not bug ,its because of list

Answer (score 4):

- Inside a list context, you need to indent code by eight spaces

  ```
    foo += bar
  ```

  and start subsequent lines with a space to keep them indented.
- If you want to have a code block right after your bullet point indented as if it wasn't in the bullet list, use a comment `<!-- -->`.

```
foo -= bar
```

Comment: Thanks :) But isn't point 2 a workaround ? It still is a bug.

Comment: I don't think it is. Since lines starting with one space are considered to be inside the list/bullet item. The four-space indent isn't enough for a code block inside the list, but it also is enough for the paragraph to be considered inside the list. You can't break that without something that's not indented at all, the parser can't tell the difference.