# Code immediately following a list does not format properly

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Formatting breaks if code follows a list:

1. List item
2. List item

   This is in a code block

   ## This does not work as expected

However, it works if between the list and the code

1. List item
2. List item

There is a line of normal text.

```
This is in a code block
# This does work as expected
```

**Edit**

To make this clear: This is **not** about nesting code in a list but about code **following** a (finished) list not working as expected (by me). To put it differently: Why is a list not considered finished despite of following empty lines? What do I have to do?

Comment: I had the same problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165215/single-line-code-formatting-after-list-not-working

Comment: While I'm marking this as a duplicate, I agree with the duplicate - there should be a more intuitive way of doing this.

Comment: @JasonSturges OK, at least I have learnt how to make list items with several paragraphs... :-)  My intuition would consider more than one blank line (or even one non-"indented" "blank" line) to mark the end of a list.

Answer (score 4):

Code nested within a list must be indented 8-spaces.

1. List item
2. List item

   ```
   This is in a code block
   # This does work as expected
   ```

For a code block immediately following a list, you can put a html comment between them:

1. List item
2. List item

```
This is in a code block
# This does work as expected
```

Comment: But this is **not** to be nested. Thus I don't understand the consideration as a duplicate. The question is then: How can a list be finished (if not by empty lines) without getting anything additional (unwanted) shown?

Comment: Put a html comment between the list and code block, as in: `<!-- -->`.