# URLs are linked despite being inside a code span

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, inline-code

Markdown source:

```
`http://google.com`

- `http://google.com`
    - `http://google.com`
```

Rendered result:

`http://google.com`

- `http://google.com`

  - `http://google.com`

Note that the third code span is a link. Adding a newline before the list item makes the link disappear.

Comment: Ohh. Now I got the actual issue. Nice edit @balpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in [both](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=8504d86e6ee100e2139a68eabddc6aef41524643) [versions](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=4aef59fd15ffc23fad7c81474ea6f3dc94af2fec) of Markdown; this is in the next build.

Markdown list items that don't contain empty lines are treated differently from list items that do (see [Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists/74115#74115) for more fun with this fact).

Lists nested within other list items, where the outer (and by deduction, also the inner) list item had no empty line, received the span-level treatment (links, code spans, bolding, etc.) multiple times. What you found was the most obvious consequence of this bug (there are less obvious ones, like the creation of nested links). Thanks for noting!

Comment: This may seem obvious, but, so, the `&gt;` appeared because that code block (due to the bug) was being treated as something in between a code and a link?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to put it. Or if you want, it was treated as both at the same time.