# extra `http` getting added with hyperlink tool

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

After trying to link to rubluar.com, I've got the error message:

```
 Links to http://http://rubular.com/r/... are not allowed.
```

After some further investigation, I've found that using the tool to automatically generate the markdown for my link has changed

```
http://rubular.com/r/KDEEwTIToq
```

to

```
http://%20http://rubular.com/r/KDEEwTIToq
```

removing the `%20http://` manually allowed the link to work.

[image]

Comment: http://refiddle.com/ (Here is a regex fiddle you can use while waiting for a fix) By the way you have put 2 times `http://` and that might cause the problem.

Comment: @HugoDozois that makes me want to edit my question

Comment: i reproduced the error before finishing my edit but i can't anymore

Comment: There were some change in the Markdown engine today, that might be related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176537/urls-are-linked-despite-being-inside-a-code-span

Answer (score 3):

That extra %20... can happen when you paste in a link with an extra space:

```
[example.com without extra space][1]

[example.com with space in front][2]


  [1]: http://example.com
  [2]: http://%20http://example.com
```

then you get the error message you saw:

```
Links to http:// http://example.com are not allowed
```