# Effect of * in quoted text not shown in preview but affected actual post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, blockquote

In my recent [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218271/66803), In quoted text of first special parameter description, The preview shows well:

[image: screenshot0]

**But in actual post `*` effect cause inclined text:**

[image: screenshot]

So, **Why preview!=actual of post?** and How to fix it?

Comment: I would use backticks around the `($*)` and `"$*"` as a workaround

Comment: @rene sems like alternative/temporary solution but not **actual**!

Comment: That is true and I stated as such at the end of my answer. In the 6 to 8 weeks until this bug get status-completed my answer can serve as the temporary workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the preview is broken. However, if the preview was correct you'd still have the same problem as `*` is part of the markdown syntax and therefore needs to be escaped by `\` when used as part of a string:

Thus `($\*) stuff*` is rendered as

> ($*) stuff*

Instead of

> ($*) stuff*

Your quote then becomes:

> ($*) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

Comment: Thnk-you, your suggestion is [implemented](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/218271/4)

Answer (score 3):

There are cornercases where the preview is different from your actual post. What you see is caused by [the intra-word emphasis feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)

The preview is, for obvious reasons, rendered client-side. When you post the markdown is parsed and transformed to HTML and stored in the Posts table. This guarantees it can be served to viewers without having to be parsed/transformed for each request.

In your specific case your use of $*) at the beginning and then have a * somewhere in the middle makes the preview renderer believe you want to make the text between the two * italic.

If that is not what you intended you can use backticks around your `$*` to indicate that those characters should be taken literally and are not part of markdown.

I agree that ideally the preview and the final rendering should be the same. Looks like [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79981/158100) has to use his [regex fu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74115/158100) once more...

Comment: It's actually the use of `*)` that causes the italics not `$*`...

Comment: ... and I missed the escaping option .... thanks @benisuǝqbackwards